# $G$ is $p$-group commutative. Prove $G$ has two distinct subgroups of order $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, analysis

$G$ is $p$-group commutative $p$ is prime. Prove $G$ is cycle or $G$ has two distinct subgroups of order $p$.

I. $G$ is cyclic.

Because $G$ is $p$-prime and abelian, it has a non-trivial center, so it is cyclic.

II. $G$ has two distinct subgroups of order $p$.

Because $G$ if $p$-group has order $p$ and since every group is a subgroup of itself we have $1$ subgroup of order $p$.

If we analyze the function

$$\phi(g)=g^p, \; g \in G,$$

we will notice that it forms a homomorphism from $G$ to $G$:

$$\phi(g.h)=(gh)^p=g^p.h^p=\phi(g).\phi(h).$$

Note that we can create a subgroup $H$ of $G$ through the image of this function.
If we can find a one-to-one function from $H$ to $G$ we will prove that $H$ has the same order as $G$, so we will have two subgroups of order $p$.
Be the function From $H$ to $G$.

$$\varphi(g^p)=g ,\; g \in G.$$

Injective:

$\varphi(g^p)=g$ and $\varphi(h^p)=g$, then $g^p=h^p$.

This function is injective because if we analyze the elements in $G$ they are of the form $p^n$.

$g^p=(p^n)^p$ and $h^p=(p^m)^p$, $m$ different $n$.

Therefore, it is injective.

Surjectivity:
It is guaranteed by the injectivity of the function $\phi(g)=g^p$.

Doubts:

1. Is my reasoning correct? If not, could you explain why and give me any tips?
2. My teacher had given me a very confusing tip which I couldn't use which would be: That from the homomorphism of the function $\phi(g)=g^p$ we should apply induction on the image of $\phi$. Is it possible to resolve the issue like this? This would help answer exactly what? Part I or part II or even both. If it is possible to use this method any advice where to start? Because I really didn't understand how to use induction in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct. The group is not necessarily cyclic. The point of the exercise is to show that if it is not cyclic, then it must contain (at least) two different subgroups of order $p$. It is perhaps worthwhile to remark at this point, that a group is cyclic if and only if it contains precisely one subgroup of every allowed order.

Assume then that $G$ is an abelian $p$-group, which is not cyclic. Then $|G|=p^n$ for some $p$, and by the basis theorem, $G$ is a direct product of at least two finite cyclic $p$-groups. Each factor in the product contains a subgroup of order $p$, and these subgroups are different, because they live inside different factors.